# copy files from multiple remote machines to local and create directories for remote machines

Tags: cp, remote, hosts, mkdir

Have multiple vm machines that am using for studying, and have come up with this script for copying some files from vm's to my local machine:

```
SG=rohos; date; for i in `cat /etc/hosts | grep "$SG-" | awk '{print $2}'` ;do echo "Logging into ${i}";ssh -i /root/.ssh/vm_private_key keyless-user@${i} "sudo mkdir -p /tmp/${SG}/${i}; sudo cp /var/some.log /tmp/${SG}/${i}/ ";done
```

What could be changed in this script so that multiple typing of destination directories for mkdir and cp could be avoided? Or if you have a better tool like rsync or something else please enlighten me.

---

```
SG=rohos
date 
for i in `cat /etc/hosts | grep "$SG-" | awk '{print $2}'` 
do 
  echo "Logging into ${i}"
  ssh -i /root/.ssh/vm_private_key keyless-user@${i} "sudo mkdir -p /tmp/${SG}/${i}; sudo cp /var/some.log /tmp/${SG}/${i}/ "
done
```

Comment: I unfold command to add readability, 1) there is a useless use of cat 2) I didn't see remote file coming back.

Comment: there's a useless use of grep there too.  The `cat | grep | awk` can be replaced with just `awk "/$SG-/ {print \$2}" /etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

Your script can't do what you want.  As written, it will only ever copy files on remote hosts to `/tmp/$SG/$i` on the same remote host.

You need to use `scp` instead of `ssh` and `cp`.  For example:

```
SG=rohos
date 
for i in $(awk "/$SG-/ {print \$2}" /etc/hosts); do 
  echo "Logging into $i"
  mkdir -p "/tmp/$SG/$i"
  scp -i /root/.ssh/vm_private_key "keyless-user@$i:/var/some.log" "/tmp/${SG}/${i}/"
done
```

If you want to preserve the timestamps and permissions of the copied files, add `-p` to the `scp` command's options.  or add `-r` for a recursive copy of entire directory trees.

See `man scp` for details of scp and its options.